# Match scroll bar scrolling to content scrolling - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll

I apologize in advanced if this is a little confusing to understand, but I'll do the best I can to explain it.

Basically I've created a scrolling page that allows you have content that extends beyond the stage and swipe up or down to view it.

In this case, a movieclip the size of the stage **masks** an object under it (taller than the stage) and swiping up/down affects the objects y position, revealing more of it.

The part I'm stuck on is getting the "scroll bar" object on the side to match the position of the top and bottom of the overflow object;

Since the scroll bar has to stay on the stage, when the bottom of the object is reached the scroll bar ends up being off stage because they move at the same speed, so in this case, the scroll bar would need to move slower in order to be at the bottom when the other object is.

The way it's coded right now I can only seem to match either the top with

```
scrollbar.y = (e.target.y - barY);
```

the opposite is achieved by

```
scrollbar.y = (e.target.y + barY);
```

but I can't seem to achieve both simultaneously.

I'm coding this in AS3 (flash CC) with mobile being my desired platform to publish, and I'll attach my code as well as some screenshots below.

```
var ease:int = 6;
var targY:int = dragMe.y;
var barY:int = scrollbar.y;

var drag:Boolean = false;
var pos:Number = 0;

var minY:Number = 0 + dragMe.height / 2; // how low the top can go
var maxY:Number = stage.stageHeight - dragMe.height / 2; // how high the bottom can go

var barMax:Number = 0 + scrollbar.height; // how high the bar can go
var barMin:Number = stage.stageHeight - scrollbar.height; // how low the bar can go

dragMe.mask = mcMask;
mcMask.visible = false;

dragMe.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dragging);
dragMe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUp);

function dragging(e:Event):void {
    if (drag) {
        targY = mouseY + pos;
    }
    // restrict scrolling to stage
    targY = Math.min(targY, minY); // how low the top can go
    targY = Math.max(targY, maxY); // how high the bottom can go

    barY = Math.min(barY, barMin); // how low the bar can go
    barY = Math.max(barY, barMax); // how high the bar can go

    // Movement of the text
    e.target.y += (targY - e.currentTarget.y) / ease;
    // Movement of the bar
    scrollbar.y = (e.target.y - barY);

}

function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    drag = false;
}

function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
    pos = e.currentTarget.y - mouseY;
    drag = true;
}
```

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

Grey = stage
Black = outside stage

Good:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvAoz.png

Bad:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvHIm.png

Comment: Where do you set the scrollBar's height?

Comment: The scroll bar is already on the stage but **barMin** and **barMax** control how high on the stage the bar should go.

If touch events are put on the bar, you can't drag it higher than the top/bottom of the stage

Answer (score 0):

> The part I'm stuck on is getting the "scroll bar" object on the side to match the position of the top and bottom of the overflow object;

Well, there's no need to get the scrollbar object to match the position of the overflow object, you should bind it to the coordinates of the masker object. Btw I usually gather all UI elements right in the IDE, and then parse them. For example, if I need to add a scroll bar, I need only three elements:

1. container - all content will be added right in it;
2. masker
3. Scrollbar movieclip, which consists of two MCs: bg and a bar.

In this case I don't need to place this elements in code, but just call in a function to handle this elements. The code itself is simple enough. You know the height of the masker, the height and the position of the container, and also the height of the scrollbar background and current position of the bar. All you need is to handle the events and react accordingly.

E.g. in case you are scrolling using your scrollbar, just translate current coordinates of the bar and update container's position. If you are dragging your content, update your bar's position accordingly.

Also, there's a better way to drag the bar:

```
private static function drag(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    var myBounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(bar.x, 0, 0, barBg.height-bar.height+8);
    bar.startDrag(false, myBounds);
    bar.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}

static private function stopdrag(e:*):void 
    {
        bar.stopDrag();
        update(null);
        bar.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

    }

    static private function update(e:Event):void 
    {
        var scroll_run_length:Number = barBg.height - bar.height + 8;
        var modificator:Number = (content.height-masker.height) / scroll_run_length;
        content.y = startContY -(bar.y * modificator);

    }
```